# tbody vertical scrollbar is only visible after horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

When the horizontal scrollbar is to the left, the vertical scrollbar is not present

[image]

When the horizontal scrollbar is to the right, the scrollbar is present

[image]

How can I make the vertical scrollbar show at all times (it should only cover `tbody`)

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-y8vci7?file=style.css) the Stackblitz

And here's the code anyway:

```css
table thead,
table tbody {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  height: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div {
  width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title 1</th>
        <th>Title 2</th>
        <th>Title 3</th>
        <th>Title 4</th>
        <th>Title 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave out `overflow: auto;` from tbody, and add `position: sticky;` to thead. Make sure to add a background-color to thead so the table's content doesn't overlap when scrolling.

```css
table thead,
table tbody {
  display: block;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}

tbody {
  height: 160px;
  /* overflow: auto; */
}

div {
  width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title 1</th>
        <th>Title 2</th>
        <th>Title 3</th>
        <th>Title 4</th>
        <th>Title 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 3</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```